# Exact eigenfunctions of two interacting identical particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interactions, identical-particles, quantum-statistics, ground-state

While I was reading about quantum states of $N$ interacting identical particles, I realized that I don't understand some fundamental things. So In order to clear my confusion, I decided to consider a toy model and work everything out for it: ground state wave-function, energy and first excited state wave-function and energy.

Consider two interacting identical particles (let's say bosons with spin $0$ or fermions with spin $\frac{1}{2}$) with Hamiltonian:
$$
H=\frac{p_1^2+p_2^2}{2m}+\frac{m\omega^2}{2}(x_1^2+x_2^2)+\frac{m\Omega^2}{2}(x_1-x_2)^2.
$$
This Hamiltonian can be easily diagonalized using the coordinates $\xi=\frac{x_1+x_2}{\sqrt{2}}$, $\eta=\frac{x_1-x_2}{\sqrt{2}}$:

eigenfunctions
$$
\psi_{n_1,n_2}(x_1,x_2)=A\exp\left\{-\frac{m\omega}{2}\xi^2-\frac{m\sqrt{\omega^2+2\Omega^2}}{2}\eta^2\right\}H_{n_1}\left(\sqrt{m\omega}\xi\right)H_{n_2}\left(\sqrt{m(\omega^2+2\Omega^2)}\eta\right),
$$
and spectrum
$$
E_{n_1,n_2}=\omega\left(n_1+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\sqrt{\omega^2+2\Omega^2}\left(n_2+\frac{1}{2}\right),\quad n_1,n_2=0,1,2... .
$$
[here $H_n$ - are Hermite polynomials.]

**1)** two identical bosons with spin $0$.

To get the ground state wave function, which is symmetric in $x_1, x_2$, we take the eigenfunction with $n_1=n_2=0$
$$
\psi_0(x_1,x_2)=\psi_{0,0}(x_1,x_2)=A\exp\left\{-\frac{m\omega}{2}\xi^2-\frac{m\sqrt{\omega^2+2\Omega^2}}{2}\eta^2\right\}
$$
since it is automatically symmetric in $x_1$ and $x_2$. Ground state energy is $E_{0,0}$. First exited state energy will be $E_{1,0}$ with eigenfunction
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\psi_{1,0}(x_1,x_2)+\psi_{1,0}(x_2,x_1)\right).
$$
We also get that this system can not have energy $E_{0,1}$ because in that case
$$
\psi_{0,1}(x_1,x_2)+\psi_{0,1}(x_2,x_1)\equiv 0
$$
since $H_1(x)$ is an odd function.

**2)** fermions with spin $\frac{1}{2}$.

Ground state is given by  $\psi_0(x_1,x_2)=\psi_{0,0}(x_1,x_2)$ and corresponds to the singlet state (total spin $S=0$) of the system of two spin $\frac{1}{2}$ fermions. Since the singlet state spin wave-function is antisymmetric, this means spatial wave-function is symmetric. First exited state energy will be $E_{1,0}$ with symmetric spatial eigenfunction
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\psi_{1,0}(x_1,x_2)+\psi_{1,0}(x_2,x_1)\right).
$$

However, unlike the boson case above, the energy $E_{0,1}$ is attainable for fermions of spin $\frac{1}{2}$ in the triplet state (with total spin $S=1$). In this case the spin wave-function is symmetric, thus the spatial wave-function needs to be antisymmetric and will be given by $\psi_{0,1}(x_1,x_2)$.

> **Question:** Is everything I wrote above correct?

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but what does $\Omega$ stand for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your calculations look correct to me but I'm missing the point of your post, if there is one apart from the check of the results.

If you need a check for what you found you can easily search for "coupled harmonic oscillators" or "particles with harmonic interactions" and you will find many examples and exercises (e.g. http://courses.physics.ucsd.edu/2009/Fall/physics130b/IdentParts.pdf )

Your evaluations about the symmetry of the wavefunctions are correct. Not all the mathematical solutions are correct physical solutions.

Comment: Thanks. I got answer to my question on page 9 of your linked paper.

Comment: Please note the policy on [check-my-work](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093) questions.

Comment: @StephenG it was not check my work. It was check my understanding. If you read my question carefully you could have seen that for yourself.

Comment: *"Is everything I wrote above correct?"* seems pretty clearly check my work to me.  This is the *only* question asked.  You don't ask about a specific concept you are unsure of but for your own analysis of a model to be checked - we don't do that (or to be precise it's against community policy).